# How to add a color gradient overlay on text using css?

Tags: css, gradient, photoshop

I have a photoshop design that has a heading color #524a48.
On the photoshop design there is a gradient-overlay on the text

```
h1 {
color: #524a48;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,239,223, 0) 0%, rgba(255,239,223, 1));
opacity: 40%;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

So the overlay gradient from opacity 0 - 1. When using this code here the color of #524a48 doesn't show and I have a half transparent line of text...
Using #524a48 as the webkit-text-fill-color value completely hides my gradient.

How can I have color overlay over the color of my text using css?
Also how can I ensure that a fallback for this? So browsers that aren't chrome or safari will see #524a48. Is passing #524a48 to the color property sufficient?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make a solution with this

You just need to edit all the alpha layer values

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,239,223, 1), rgba(255,239,223, 1));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(82,74,72,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>LINEAR GRADIENT TEXT</h1>
</div>
```

With how this works, I don't see another way to do what you are suggesting

Other then create an absolute div with exact same contents directly over this one and specifying the color property.  I would go with the first solution